# asana API integration fails in JAVA

Tags: java, asana

Tried to integrate asana API with java,struts project.
By using javasana class i succeeded to get workspaces,users etc
Now my requirement is to add tasks to asana.So i tried to configure API using following configuartion with th help of mvn repositories. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.joelinn/asana/0.5.4
So included following jars in lib folder

```
1)asana-0.5.4.jar
2)guava-15.0.jar
3)jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar
4)jersey-client-1.17.1.jar
5)junit-4.11.jar
```

Now its showing method not found error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.codehaus.jackson.map.MappingJsonFactory.setCodec(Lorg/codehaus/jackson/ObjectCodec;)Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory
```

Code i wrote for adding task

```
Asana asana=new Asana(apiKey);
        asana.tasks().createTask(new TaskRequestBuilder(workspaceId,"project-followup").addFollower(followassigneeuserId).notes("The task is to follow up user on project system").assignee(assigneeuserId));
```

may i know where i am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jackson jar

```
3)jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar
```

depends on two jars

```
* jackson-core-asl   
* jackson-mapper-asl
```

which you can again get from the above link, If you include those every thing fine

Comment: did this example worked for you? I am not able to get task list at all.